# Android Java - Broadcast Receiver - App Notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to detect when android notification settings have been changed (API 26+)? I have tried to find intent in Broadcast Receiver but no luck.

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="???App Notification Settings Change???" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by looking in SDK file - broadcast_actions.
The following works:

```
<action android:name="android.app.action.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED" />
```